# How to read 50MB xls excel file using spring and hibernate

Tags: java

Code read only .xlsx format only.

```
InputStream in = lob.getBinaryStream();
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(in);
XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader(pkg);
SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();
```

How can I read a 50MB xls excel file in Java?

Comment: What is your Problem with the above code? Also Spring and Hibernate have nothing to do with reading excel files.

Comment: Wrongly added Spring and Hibernate... I would like to read more than 50MB xls file.. The code shared by me, is able to read 1 GB .xlsx file

Comment: Suggest me.. How to read 50MB .xls file

Answer (score 1):

First things first: reading Excel files has nothing to do with Spring and Hibernate. You're using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) library. `XSSFReader` is a class for reading XLSX files, that's why you can't read XLS file with it. There's a detailed and commented example of reading data from **both** XLS and XLSX files at [CalliCoder](https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-excel-file-apache-poi/) site. I will just copy here a short snippet to get you started:

```
public class ExcelReader {
    public static final String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = "./sample-xlsx-file.xlsx";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));
        System.out.println("Workbook has " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " Sheets : ");
        for(Sheet sheet: workbook) {
            System.out.println("=> " + sheet.getSheetName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code base shared by you, will not read more than 50MB file. It will give GC Overhead limit exceeded... That why I shared OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(in);
XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader(pkg);
technique